# Remove private PyPi index from local virtual env

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I have somehow managed to mess up my pip indexes for a local virtual env.

`pip config list` returns the following
`:env:.index-url='https://***/private-pypi/simple/' global.index-url='https://pypi.python.org/simple'`

This makes pip to always default to searching the private pypi index first. Any idea how I can remove the env specific index? It does not appear in the pip.conf file and running `pip config unset env.index-url` does not work either or I can't get the right syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should check env.

use `env | grpe PIP` cmd, and will find `PIP_INDEX_URL` look like this

```bash
PIP_INDEX_URL=xxx
```